# Is ther a way to get the package name given the import name in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python scripts we can usually find some import statements. Sometime the system may not have the the required package installed. Even if we try to install the package using the name from import statement, it might not work always as package name and import name could be different.

For example assume a python script downloaded from internet has the following import statement.
    import win32com

The actual package name that contains the win32com is pywin32 in Python 3. The names are different.

I would like to have a script that identifies the package name from import name so that it makes the life of users easier.

Comment: Try `pip search`

Comment: pip search is not very efficient. I have tried in the past. We have to use the pypi cli probably

Comment: Be aware that there are multiple projects on PyPI that use the same module name. For example, there's an `attr` package clashing with the much more popular `attrs`, and `google` got nabbed by some Google TOS-breaking search thing that conflicts with the name of the namespace package a bunch of actual Google stuff uses.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Are you really trying to figure out dependencies from import statements?

Comment: I think it is a valid use case. We read code in github etc There are a bunch of imports. Now to make these imports available in your PYTHONPATH, what package/packages do we install?

Comment: The usual way is to provide a `requirements.txt` (for plain `pip`) or `Pipfile` (for `pipenv`) to indicate the dependencies for the project. Note that knowing the name of the distribution is not sufficient, you need to know the correct version to install too.

Comment: @rdas yes i am trying to find the deps from imports.

Comment: @Selcuk In general we download some sample python scripts from internet for example code. They are not shipped along with requirements.txt, so i am trying to figure the deps without it. I agree the version also matters but that would be a secondary case for now

Comment: That's not an easy task for the reasons @user2357112 has already explained. Even if you can resolve the names, you still have to figure out which versions of those packages are targeted. It is not easy even to determine the Python version needed for a random script downloaded from the Internet.

Comment: @Selcuk yeah i know its not easy but i am trying for it